# Api route is blocked by huge process in event loop

Tags: node.js, rest, api

I have a restify api similar to this (i write in pseudocode) :

```
server.post('api/import') 
{

  database.write(status of this file.id is pending)
  fileModification(req.file)
  res.status(200)
  res.send(import has started)
} //here I do some file modifications and then i import it to database
server.get('api/import_info') 
{
  database.select(file status)
} //here I want to see status (is file imported or pending(process is not finished yet))

//In another module after import is finished I update database to 
database.write(file.id import status is completed)
```

Importing file is process that takes about 2 minutes, but even I don't wait for it to finish in api/import when I try to trigger 'info' route my api is blocked

Is it possible that event loop is blocked or maybe connection is not properly closed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us the REAL code for the importing file operation that is blocking the event loop.  If it's improperly using synchronous file I/O, then it should be converted to asynchronous file I/O so other requests can run while it's waiting on file I/O.  If it's just doing lots of CPU-intensive stuff, then you will need to move it to another  process or thread in any number of ways.

Comment: You can see the various options for engaging other CPUs here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384542/do-nodejs-async-functions-use-all-cpu-cores/58384746#58384746 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917341/how-to-process-huge-array-of-objects-in-nodejs/56919401#56919401.

Answer (score 1):

I have some ideas about your question.

1. you can use **cluster module** [Cluster](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/cluster.html), **cluster module** can create process depend on your cpu core. When on process blocked, Others process still can work.
2. you can fork a new process in your api, use the new process handle your task.